# Observe MyArray().length knock out

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to store length on an observable array in an observable variable and bind this to the view, something like this?

```
self.MyArray = ko.observableArray([]);
self.MyArraylength = self.MyArray().length;
//Bind in view
self.Observelength = ko.observable(self.MyArraylength);
```

When I alert MyArray length it seems to update proper, but cant get it to update in view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because MyArrayLength isn't observable, it won't update when the observable does. You need a computed function instead.

You should have:

```
self.MyArray = ko.observableArray([]);
// bind in view
self.Observelength = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.MyArray().length;
});
```

Comment: fixed the length check

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following statements:

```
self.MyArraylength = self.MyArray().length;    
ko.observable(self.MyArraylength);
```

Are merely containing a Number as their value. There is no longer a reference to the original array or its length.

You need to *compute* the length instead:

```
self.ObserveLength = function() {
    return self.MyArray().length;
};
```

Alternatively, you can `subscribe` for changes on the array and update the `length` then:

```
self.MyArray.subscribe(function() {
    self.MyArraylength = self.MyArray().length;
});
```